# How to update Database Table when multiple rows are edited in Gridview

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

I have inserted the screenshot of my Windows Form which pulls up information from a Product Table:

[image: Windows Form]

Now as you can see i have allowed the option to `Modify` and then `Save` the modifications in the Database Table. So the issue i am facing is in updating the data in the Database Table. Since the user can update more than 1 row at a time in the `GridView`, how do i update the Database table?

I can either do a row-wise update, or i can loop through the `GridView` and update my table and then use a Command Builder.

I want know how do i achieve the solution in both scenarios.

Comment: What scenarios do you mean in the end, is it the "updating one row" and "updating several rows" scenarios? What is your question? "How do I update the database table", "Which solution should I use", or "Give me the solutions for both of the above scenarios please"?

Comment: Updating several rows at a time. One using Datatable table and the other looping through Gridview and passing an insert command on each iteration.

Comment: So what are you actually asking, how you detect if the user updated several rows? Do you have any problems with using either of the two solutions you suggest? Would you mind clarifying the problem you are facing? Is it that you are unable to update the database, or that you are unsure what the best solution is to do it?

Comment: Yes first thing i would like to know if the user updated any rows.. and then how do i save multiple row updates at the same time?

Comment: Have you looked at the events given by the DataGridView, such as the [CellValueChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx) event? If you do you can simply store the row index of the changed cell in a set for instance, and when you click save you go through the collection and update each one in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through the rows and pass the values to a parameter and then update in database. One thing, it is more work that doesn't need to be done. But another thing that helps is you know whatever cell they edit will be committed to the database.